# Unable to cast to protocol from framework during test cases

Tags: swift, xctest

So I have a class that comes from one of our internal frameworks. It is defined as follows:

```
// This lives within a framework
class ExternalClass: ExternalClassProtocol {
    // implementation here
}

// This lives within my test target
class MockExternalClass: ExternalClassProtocol {
    // Mock implementation here
}

// This lives within the same external frame work as ExternalClass
protocol ExternalClassProtocol: AnyObject {
   // Protocol methods here  
}
```

During my test cases, if I try to cast MockExternalClass as? ExternalClassProtocol, the test case crashes.

However, during live app runtime, there is no problem casting ExternalClass as? ExternalClassProtocol.

Is this an issue with trying to implement a protocol from an external module? Is there a way around this?

The class is being accessed through dependency injection (see below dependency injection implementation). The crash occurs on the resolve function.

**If you actually debug to this point, you can see that the mock dependency IS in my dependency root (the services array below).**

So I know its not failing to cast due to the dependency being missing.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Injected<Value> {
    var key: String

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { return Dependency.root.resolve(key: self.key) }
        set { Dependency.root.add(key: self.key, newValue) }
    }

    init(key: String) {
        self.key = key
    }
}


class Dependency {
    static let root = Dependency()

    var services: [String : Any] = [:]

    func add<T>(key: String, _ service: T) {
        services[key] = service
    }

    func resolve<T>(key: String) -> T {
        guard let component: T = services[key] as? T else {
            // The test crashes here. It works fine on other mocks that are internal to the project
            fatalError("Dependency '\(T.self)' not resolved!")
        }

        return component
    }

    func clearDependencies() {
        self.services.removeAll()
    }

    private init() {}
}
```

In my test case:

```
@testable import MyProject
import ExternalDependency

class TestCase: XCTestCase {
    private var subject: ClassWithService!
    private var mockInternalClass: MockInternalClassProtocol!
    private var mockExternalClass: MockInternallClassProtocol!

    func setUp() {
        mockExternalClass = MockExternalClass() // This one crashes when trying to cast to its parent protocol
        mockInternalClass = MockInternalClass() // This one does not crash when casting to parent protocol.
        Dependency.root.add(key: "internal_class", mockInternalClass)
        Dependency.root.add(key: "external_class", mockExternalClass)
    }
}
```

Some things I've tried:

Adding AnyObject to the protocol (this fixed a similar issue for internally defined classes that I mock).

changing mockExternalClass type to be the protocol
changing mockExternalClass type to be the implementation

Aside from one protocol being defined in one of our pods, there is no difference between the external protocol and the one we have defined in our own project.

One thing I have noticed is that the cast does not fail if you set a break point inside one of my test case functions. But if you try the same cast within the Dependency.resolve function it crashes. Which leads me to believe there is an issue with the generics.

Any ideas?

Comment: The fatal error could be reached because the item is missing from the `services` array or it could be reached because the item is there, but is not of the correct type. Try reorganizing your code so that you can know which of the reasons causes the fatal error.

Comment: @Rudedog as I mentioned in the original post. Its not missing from the services array.

The issue is that its failing to cast. Specifically in that resolve function. If you try to do the cast within the test case, it casts fine. Is it possible that its failing because of the use of generics? Or maybe because the protocol is not defined in the main application, but rather one of my Pods?